# In QGIS, how to apply the style from one layer to another, while categories in layers partially diverse?

Tags: qgis

I have two layers loaded into QGIS which overlap in some categories but not in all, and one layer has more categories than the other.

I tried it by `right-click on layer1  --> Styles --> Copy Style --> Symbology`, then `right click on layer 2 --> Styles --> Paste Style --> Symbology`. But the result is, that the layer, wo which i copied the symbology-style isn't shown in QGIS anymore.

How can I copy the style of one layer to the other, when the layers overlap only in some categories and diverse in amount of categories?

Comment: Copy it, then manually edit the categories to fit the new layer. Or maybe you can set a preset for categories, haven't tried that so far.

Comment: Hi @Erik, how can I edit the style? When I copied it, like described in my question, it seems to be stored in memory, not as a file.

Comment: Double click a category, enter a new value, press enter.

Comment: If even the `else` condition is not rendered anymore, it could be because a field name from layer1 is not found in layer2, so the whole ruleset is invalid. Otherwise add/edit categories